# Comparing a simple list with a list with sublists in Racket

Tags: list, racket

How can i compare one simple list with a list which contains three or more sublists and get two sublists that matches the list the most? I know that my code is completely wrong but can someone help me?

Here is how i defined the list which contains sublists:

```
(define db (list '('green 'blue 'yellow 'orang)
             '('black 'blue 'darkblue 'white)
             '('brown 'red 'turkos 'pink)))
```

The simple list:

```
(define indata '('green 'blue ))
```

An the code:

```
(define (compare lst database)
  (define (compare-help lst database result)
    (cond
      ((null? database) result)
      ((equal? (car lst) (car (car database)))
       (cons (car database) result))
       (else
        (compare-help  (lst (cdr database) result))))
  (compare-help lst database '())))

 > (compare indata db)
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
('green 'blue 'yellow 'orang) ('black 'blue 'darkblue 'white))
```

Comment: "get two sublists that matches the list the most", what does it mean to match 'the most'? For example, if you gave `'("blue" "red")`, what two lists would it return?

Comment: Your question is still very fuzzy. What does it mean for a list to "match the most"? (Also, side note: do not put quoted symbols inside of a quoted list; quoting a list already causes the enclosed identifiers to be read as symbols)

Comment: For example the simple list in this case has two elements 'blue and 'green. The output should be the sublists that contains both 'blue and 'green and the sublists that contains 'blue or 'green. Because the first sublist contains both 'blue and 'green it is the first element (the whole sublist) of the output. And the second sublist contains just blue. That's why it should be the second element of the output. that's how i meant by "match the most" .

Thanks for your respond.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your input data are incorrect.

Compare the output of `db`, `db2` and `db3`.

```
#lang racket

(define db (list '('green 'blue 'yellow 'orang)
                 '('black 'blue 'darkblue 'white)
                 '('brown 'red 'turkos 'pink)))

(define db2 '((green blue yellow orange)
              (black blue darkblue white)
              (brown red turkos pink)))


(define db3 (list (list 'green 'blue 'yellow   'orange)
                  (list 'black 'blue 'darkblue 'white)
                  (list 'brown 'red  'turkos   'pink)))

db
db2
db3
```

Output:

```
'(('green 'blue 'yellow 'orang) ('black 'blue 'darkblue 'white) ('brown 'red 'turkos 'pink))
'((green blue yellow orange) (black blue darkblue white) (brown red turkos pink))
'((green blue yellow orange) (black blue darkblue white) (brown red turkos pink))
```

Take away: A quote `'` is not equivalent to `list`.

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I compare one simple list with a list which contains three or more sublists and get two sublists that matches the list the most?
2. How can I compare one *simple list* with a list that contains three or more sublists and get the two sublists that *match* the *simple list* the *most*?
3. How can I to process a list that contains three or more lists in it, and get back the two that *match* a given list *the most*?
4. How can I process a list?  -- *by Recursion!*

   ```
   (define (process lst)
       (apply (lambda (a . d)    ; a is the "car"
                  (process d))   ; d is the "cdr"
              lst))
   ```

   b. But what if the `lst` is empty?  -- *by handling this case!*

   ```
   (define (process lst)
     (cond
       ((null? lst) 'WE_ARE_DONE!)
       (else
         (apply (lambda (a . d)    ; a is the "car"
                    (process d))   ; d is the "cdr"
                lst))))
   ```
5. OK, but I do nothing here. How do I *do something* with each element?  -- *by adding internal definitions and using them:*

   ```
   (define (process lst)
     (define result #f)
     (define (do-something-with a) 
        (set! result a))
     (define (ok-now-really-do-it lst)
       (cond
         ((null? lst) 'WE_ARE_DONE!)
         (else
           (apply (lambda (a . d)    ; a is the "car"
                    (do-something-with a)
                    (ok-now-really-do-it d))   ; d is the "cdr"
                lst))))
     (ok-now-really-do-it lst))
   ```
6. Great! I seem to have implemented the `last-elem` function, though it always tells me `WE_ARE_DONE` in the end. I can fix it, can I, and do it with a much simpler code, using `map`?  -- *Yes, `map` is very similar, also traversing an input list and applying a function to each value in it:*

   ```
   (define (process lst)
     (define result #f)
     (define (do-something-with a) 
        (set! result a))
     (map do-something-with 
          lst)
     result)
   ```
7. Huh, indeed we can just use `map`, instead of all that hand-written "processing" stuff. Great. But we've never talked about the *matching* yet, have we?  -- *Something like this?*

   ```
   (define (list-matches lst mylist)
     (define result '())
     (define (do-something-with a) 
        (set! result (insert a (matches a)
                             result)))
     (define (matches a)
        (sum (map (lambda (word) 
                     (if (word-present-in word mylist)
                         0
                         1))
                  a)))                       
     (map do-something-with lst)
     (first-two-of result))
   ```
8. `word-present-in`? How do we find this? By `process`ing the `mylist`, aren't we?

   ```
     (define (word-present-in word mylist)
        ....
        ....   (if (equal word a)
        ....     .... )
        .... )
   ```

Well. We've covered some third of the way. Or maybe quarter. Can you go along further? Implement more and more of those new names we've used here, maybe adding and *implementing* new ones as we need them, according to *how we've used them*?

For one thing, your `insert` will insert an `a`, together with its matching count, into the `result` in the *sorted order*, so that when you will take the first two *in the end*, those will be the *most matched*.

Comment: insert is unbound identifier. How did you defined "insert"?

Comment: you should do that. :) I've only covered a third of the way.

Comment: You question is too broad, really. There are many sub-tasks. Well, *several*. Try to complete  the overall scheme, define and implement each of the tasks. If you have problems there, ask more focused, *specific* questions about each subtask as you need to, with relevant code.

Comment: But can you please tell me how insert is gonna work?? ;)

Comment: you will insert an `a` together with its matching count, into the `result` in the *sorted order*, so that when you will take the first two *in the end*, those will be the *most matched*.